# MongoDB Aggregate does not properly Sort

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I've got the following query that works fine. However adding a sort to the aggregation pipeline does not actually sort it. It does change the order of the results but does not properly sort.

Any idea why it refuses to sort the results by date?

```
db.calls.aggregate({
    $match: {
        '_id.date': {
            $gte: ISODate('2014-04-13T00:00:00.000Z'),
            $lte: ISODate('2014-04-20T00:00:00.000Z')
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        calls: 1,
        year: {
            $year: '$_id.date'
        },
        month: {
            $month: '$_id.date'
        },
        day: {
            $dayOfMonth: '$_id.date'
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            name: "$_id.name",
            day: '$day',
            year: '$year',
            month: '$month'
        },
        date: {
            '$first': '$_id.date'
        },
        calls: {
            '$sum': '$calls'
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: '$_id.name',
        records: {
            $addToSet: {
                date: '$date',
                calls: '$calls'
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        'records.date': 1
    }
})
```

Outputs:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "a",
            "records" : [ 
                {
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-04-13T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "calls" : 522
                }, 
                {
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-04-16T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "calls" : 1523
                }, 
                {
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-04-20T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "calls" : 57
                }, 
                {
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-04-14T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "calls" : 1540
                }, 
                {
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-04-15T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "calls" : 1592
                }, 
                {
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-04-17T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "calls" : 1466
                }, 
                {
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-04-18T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "calls" : 1003
                }, 
                {
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-04-19T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "calls" : 623
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "b",
            "records" : [ 
                {
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-04-15T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "calls" : 102
                }, 
                {
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-04-17T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "calls" : 97
                }, 
                {
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-04-16T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "calls" : 116
                }, 
                {
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-04-13T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "calls" : 118
                }, 
                {
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-04-14T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "calls" : 142
                }, 
                {
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-04-19T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "calls" : 68
                }, 
                {
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-04-18T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "calls" : 100
                }, 
                {
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-04-20T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "calls" : 6
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "c",
            "records" : [ 
                {
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-04-17T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "calls" : 137130
                }, 
                {
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-04-14T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "calls" : 139497
                }, 
                {
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-04-13T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "calls" : 92166
                }, 
                {
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-04-18T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "calls" : 123129
                }, 
                {
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-04-15T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "calls" : 146390
                }, 
                {
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-04-20T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "calls" : 4515
                }, 
                {
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-04-16T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "calls" : 141792
                }, 
                {
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-04-19T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "calls" : 104847
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Document structure:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "date" : ISODate("2014-04-08T12:00:00.000Z"),
        "name" : "a"
    },
    "calls" : 515
}
```

---

Fixed by doing a $sort before the last group and switching out $addToSet with $push so the order is preserved.

```
db.calls.aggregate({
    $match: {
        '_id.date': {
            $gte: ISODate('2014-04-13T00:00:00.000Z'),
            $lte: ISODate('2014-04-20T00:00:00.000Z')
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        calls: 1,
        year: {
            $year: '$_id.date'
        },
        month: {
            $month: '$_id.date'
        },
        day: {
            $dayOfMonth: '$_id.date'
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            name: "$_id.name",
            day: '$day',
            year: '$year',
            month: '$month'
        },
        date: {
            '$first': '$_id.date'
        },
        calls: {
            '$sum': '$calls'
        }
    }
}, {
        $sort: {
            date: 1
        }
    }, {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id.name',
            records: {
                $push: {
                    date: '$date',
                    calls: '$calls'
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: I think it works fine but just for sorting queries result (it sorted 3 groups) , try to add $sort in each query. and tell us result.

Comment: You mean add $sort after each query in the pipeline? Shouldn't just one $sort at the end of the pipeline be enough? I've tried adding $sort after each query in the pipeline and while it does seem to give a slightly different result (regarding sorting) it is still not properly sorted.

Comment: The input to the `$sort` phase of the pipeline are 3 documents (with `_id` values a, b and c).  Now the `$sort` stage would only sort the documents, not the elements inside the `records` array, which is why the results aren't what you expect.

Comment: In addition if you want order preserved you need to use $push, sets are not order in MongoDB as such $push will preserve the order within the subdocument.

Comment: Thanks Sammaye. This was the missing key in my query. If any of you want to formulate this in an answer I will be glad to mark it as answered.

Comment: @Sammaye Thanks a lot... Its really helpful... Work like a charm....